# Can someone redistribute the ipa downloaded from app store to jailbreak users?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, jailbreak

In other words, can the ipa downloaded from app store be installed on the jailbreak iPhone directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately, you have to crack the .ipa-file first.

This can be done in an app like Crackulous. [Crackulous info here](http://hackulo.us/wiki/Crackulous)

Comment: *unfortunate* for whom?  thieves?